# how to use substr for comma separated values in table in sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, sqlite

I have a table in my database in SQLITE which has x and y co-ordinates in location field as (10,10).
I want to use the x co-ordinate and y co-ordinate separately by using a select query. I know we can use subtr and charAtIndex to  locate the position but I am not sure how to do it ?
I am new to sqlite and need some help to sort this out.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Larry: Looks like lifemoveson wants to use the coordinates in a where clause so doing the string mangling outside the database would end up being a client-side table scan (rather than an in-database table scan). I don't know how much of a difference it would make with SQLite though. `charAtIndex` makes me think Objective-C so probably Obj-C on iOS.

Comment: @Larry: Sorry I didnt see your comments before but yeah as mu is too short mentioned I am using Obj-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite's string functions are fairly limited but you abuse its implicit type conversions to split your string. Something like this should do it:

```
select xy + 0 as x,
       substr(xy, length(xy + 0) + 2) as y
from some_table
```

That should work as long as you don't have any leading zeros or spaces or internal spaces. Adding zero turns the value into a number so `'10,5' + 0` becomes just `10`; then calling `length` on that turns it back into a string and gives you the string length, then adjust that to account for the comma (`+1`) and length-to-offset (`+1`) change and you'll get your 5 out of `'10,5'`.

For example:

```
sqlite> select '10,5' + 0 as x, substr('10,5', length('10,5' + 0) + 2) as y;
x|y
10|5
```

That said, you really should redesign your schema to have separate columns for the X and Y coordinates, storing structured data inside a single column is generally a bad idea.

---

**Update for comments**: SQLite will also let you do things like this:

```
select value,
       xy + 0 as x,
       substr(xy, length(xy + 0) + 2) as y
from some_table
where x < 2000
  and y < 2000
```

or even:

```
select value
from some_table
where (xy + 0) < 2000
  and substr(xy, length(xy + 0) + 2) < 2000
```

These sorts of queries will end up doing full table scans though so they might be too slow for you. Fixing your schema to have separate X and Y coordinate columns OTOH would give you fast queries.

Comment: @MU_IS_TOO_SHORT : Is it possible to use the same logic in where clause like separating the value 10,5 to location.x and location.y: select value from t where location.x < 2000 and location.y < 2000;

Comment: @lifemoveson: Yes, you can do things like, please see my updated answer.

Comment: @mu_is_too_short : The second string which is y doesnot get the correct value if y < 2000 but x gives the correct value. I am not sure if I need to change anything here other than above mentioned since I tried that before.

Comment: @lifemoveson: What does your data really look like? And why can't you fix your schema to have separate X and Y columns?

Comment: yeah I will do that because this thing is driving me crazy too. I believe that is a better solution. But I def appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you really should put `x` and `y` in their own columns.

Here's a way to get `x` if you can't do that:

```
sqlite> select * from t;
10,10
(11,11)
(12,13)
sqlite> select rtrim(rtrim(ltrim(coord,'('),'0123456789)'),',')  from t;
10
11
12
sqlite>
```

Getting `y` woud be similar.

Answer (score 0):

If there's any way you can change your schema, then you should store your x and y coordinates in separate, numeric based fields.  This will increase performance since you won't need to do any sub-string processing and decrease the complexity of your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the bug in the designing the database. For Example: You are designing a table for rectangle then co-ordinates should be separate attributes rather than keeping them together. One row of the rectangle will represent the one Instance of the rectangle and their values are co-ordianates, length breadth etc.
If you designed the database with such a great design will be really efficient for the operations.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite substr function is not really usable for this, and using the C substr functions is a bit "picky".  Simplest is to convert to NSString and use componentsSeparatedByString or componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet to return you a nice simple NSArray of the individual comma-separated values, without the need to code any iteration.

[But if you want to select on that field you have a problem -- no SQLite function that I know of will enable it, other than perhaps "like", which would be very clumsy to use.]

Comment: You can make it work with `substr` if you don't mind abusing SQLite's type system a little bit.

Comment: Yep, a couple of people have made me a liar.  And I really like (though simultaneously despise) such clever tricks, so I should probably have bated my response a bit.

Comment: As far as tricks go, there's a fine line between clever and stupid :) We convinced him to fix his schema so it all worked out okay in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json's functions, if you have the json1 extension. If your data is really (10, 10). You can do

```
select
  json_extract(replace(replace(value, '(', '['), ')', ']'), '$[0]') as x,
  json_extract(replace(replace(value, '(', '['), ')', ']'), '$[1]') as y
from myTable
where x >= 10 AND y <= 10
```

The idea is to convert your data to valid json and use json's functions to work on.
You can find more functions in documentation here:  https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html